# Error creating quickstar maven project IntelliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, tapestry

I have the following error when I try to create a Maven Project using quickstart archetype. I am using IntelliJ 2018.

This are the steps I do:

[Select archetype](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aD3qX.png)

[Maven configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7gH3.png)

This is the error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: org.apache.maven.archetype.exception.ArchetypeGenerationFailure: Error merging velocity templates: Lexical error,   Encountered: "\ufffd" (65533), after : "" at archetype-resources/src/main/webapp/mybootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot[line 16, column 21] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] Maven execution terminated abnormally (exit code 1)
```

pomp.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>TestMaven</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestMaven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


</project>
```

Moreover, the project is empty, just pomp.xml and intellij files.

Enought reputation to add the pictures.

Comment: Please check https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TAP5-2579.

Answer (score 0):

This may be an existing compatibility problem with maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1.

Well, to solve this prolem, you can use `maven-archetype-plugin:2.4` instead of `maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1`

And I think there is no big diffrence between them in this case.

just use this maven parameter:

```
 -DarchetypeVersion=2.4 org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.4:generate
```